# Flattening the query result

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am having some problems with creating a SQL query to flat my records. I will show the example gonna be easier

Table looks like this

[image]

And as the result i would like to have this table

[image]

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try *grouping by* while using `case` to filter required records:

```
  select ProductId,
         Sum(case 
               when MesurementType = 0 then Weight
               else 0
             end) "Weight calculated",
         Sum(case 
               when MesurementType = 1 then Weight
               else 0
             end) "Weight Weight measured"
    from MyTable
group by ProductId
```

Oracle provides `Decode` function which can make the query shorter:

```
  select ProductId,
         Sum(Decode(MesurementType, 0, Weight, 0)) "Weight calculated",
         Sum(Decode(MesurementType, 1, Weight, 0))  "Weight Weight measured"
    from MyTable
group by ProductId
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have 2 rows for each product Id we can modify the above answer a bit.

```
select ProductId,
     case 
           when MesurementType = 0 then Weight
           else 0
         end "Weight calculated",
      case 
           when MesurementType = 1 then Weight
           else 0
         end "Weight measured"
from MyTable
```

group by ProductId

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation is definitely the way to go.  However, if the measurement types only take on `1` and `0`, you can simply use arithmetic:

```
select productid,
       sum(weight * (measurementtype - 1)) as weight_calculated,
       sum(weight * measurementtype) as weight_measured
from t
group by productid;
```